# Amplify is downloading layers into function zip after CLI update

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, aws-lambda-layers

A handful of my functions include libraries that are not included in lambda environment in the form of layers.
This worked just fine with Amplify CLI 5.0.2. I recently upgraded to 5.3.
After the upgrade I pushed to amplify and I ran into a max memory issue for a lot of my functions. Amplify downloaded all the libraries into the function zip file which exceeds the max memory for the code zip file.

I cannot figure out what happened and how to fix it..

I ended up reverting back to 5.0.2 but for some reason the amplify template does the same thing.

Another interesting thing keeps happening that is causing a problem.

Since I couldn't figure out how to fix the memory problem I decided to delete the function and try to remake it. I delete the function, pushed it. Added another function with the same name of the one I delete. Kept everything default, and pushed. And weirdly, it downloaded all the layers to the code zip folder, which was the same problem I had before..

What the heck is going on??

Answer (score 0):

[This is where the problem was](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShpIx.png)

If you put the libraries in the [packages] section, it will build an environment with the packages included. They should be in the [dev-packages] section.